# Сумма квадратов прогрессии. Противоречивые вычисления в sympy

Tags: python, математика, sympy

Помогите разобраться в неоднозначном поведении модуля sympy в python. Исходная задача: нахождение суммы квадратов арифметической прогрессии. Сразу скажу, что я уже вывел аналитическое решение, которое приведу внизу, а здесь меня интересует исключительно реализация суммирования в sympy python.

Итак, обозначения:

- `a` - первый член прогрессии;
- `b` - последний член прогрессии;
- `s` - шаг прогрессии;
- `n` - количество членов прогрессии

Величины `n` и `s` взаимно преобразуются друг в друга выражением:

[image: s=\frac{b-a}{n-1}]

Сумму квадратов прогрессии я записал с помощью такого выражения:

[image: S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(a+ks)^2}]

Теперь записываю это выражение в sympy. Попытка №1:

```
a, b, s, k = symbols('a, b, s, k')
n = (b - a) / s + 1
sum = Sum((a+k*s)**2, (k, 0, n-1))
sum = sum.doit()
sum = sum.simplify()
sympy.pprint(sum)
```

Получаю вывод:

[image: S=\frac{b^3-a^3}{3s}+\frac{b^2+a^2}{2}+\frac{s(b-a)}{6}]

Ответ неверный (верный ответ смотри внизу).

Теперь попытка №2. Заметим, что число `n` обязано быть целым, а `a`, `b` и `s` - нет. В верхнем пределе суммы получается выражение `(b-a)/s`, которое, как мы знаем, целое, но python об этом не знает. Поэтому перепишем код так, чтобы `n` было символом, а `s` - выражением:

```
a, b, n, k = symbols('a, b, n, k')
s = (b - a) / (n - 1)
sum = Sum((a+k*s)**2, (k, 0, n-1))
sum = sum.doit()
sum = sum.simplify()
sympy.pprint(sum)
```

На мой взгляд, это более правильный код, выполняющий аналогичную работу, но он выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Sergey\Projects\PMK\Эксперименты\HDOP\progr.py", line 15, in <module>
    sum = sum.doit()

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 241, in doit
    newf = eval_sum(f, (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 1026, in eval_sum
    value = eval_sum_symbolic(f.expand(), (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 1140, in eval_sum_symbolic
    s = eval_sum_symbolic(with_i, (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 1148, in eval_sum_symbolic
    rsum = eval_sum_symbolic(R, (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 1148, in eval_sum_symbolic
    rsum = eval_sum_symbolic(R, (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 1148, in eval_sum_symbolic
    rsum = eval_sum_symbolic(R, (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 1132, in eval_sum_symbolic
    lrsum = telescopic(L, R, (i, a, b))

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\concrete\summations.py", line 969, in telescopic
    sol = solve(L.subs(i, i + m) + R, m) or []

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1095, in solve
    solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)

  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1458, in _solve
    gen = f_num.match(D.xreplace({d: w}))[w]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Текст ошибки понятен, но, поскольку она возникает в глубине библиотеки sympy, разобраться в её причине сложно.

Теперь два вопроса:

1. Почему при первой попытке получился неверный ответ?
2. Почему во втором варианте возникает ошибка?

Теперь привожу правильную формулу суммы квадратов арифметической прогрессии:

[image: S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(a+ks)^2}=\frac{n(2a^2n-a^2+abn-4ab+2b^2n-b^2)}{6(n-1)}]

Проверка:

```
def calcSumSq(a, b, n):
    sum = 0
    for k in np.linspace(a, b, n):
        sum += k**2
    return sum

def calc(a, b, n):
    return n * (2*a**2*n - a**2 + 2*a*b*n - 4*a*b + 2*b**2*n - b**2) / 6 / (n-1)

def test(a, b, n):
    s1 = calcSumSq(a, b, n)
    s2 = calc(a, b, n)
    print(s1 == s2, "Expected:", s1, "Actual:", s2)
    
test(1, 10, 10)
test(10, 20, 11)
test(5, 20, 4)
test(4, 10, 10)
test(-40, -20, 5)
test(-40, -10, 8)
test(-40, 20, 4)
```

Вывод проверки:

```
True Expected: 385.0 Actual: 385.0
True Expected: 2585.0 Actual: 2585.0
True Expected: 750.0 Actual: 750.0
True Expected: 526.6666666666666 Actual: 526.6666666666666
True Expected: 4750.0 Actual: 4750.0
True Expected: 5771.428571428572 Actual: 5771.428571428572
True Expected: 2400.0 Actual: 2400.0
```

Comment: Как [видите](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28a%2Bk*%28%28b-a%29%2F%28n-1%29%29%29%5E2%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D+-+%28b%5E3-a%5E3%29%2F%283*%28%28b-a%29%2F%28n-1%29%29%29-%28b%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29%2F2-%28b-a%29%2F6*%28b-a%29%2F%28n-1%29), формулы тождественны...

Comment: @Harry, перепроверил и убедился, что тождественны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обе ваши формулы тождественны. Первая формула выражает сумму через `a,b,s`, а вторая через `a,b,n`. Если подставлять значения для проверки, обе формулы возвращают одно и то же значение. Более того, если в первой формуле выразить `s` через `n`, то получится в точности вторая формула.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gN2EHkFpX37cv5tJ-ksudCIrEVsU-zpR?usp=sharing

Что касается ошибки с `NoneType` при суммировании, то она иногда случается. В таких случаях я пробую как-то изменить формулу, и потом трансформировать. В этой сумме `s` и `n` связаны выражением, поэтому логично было попробовать сначала упростить без учёта связи, а затем дополнить выражением для `s`.

```
a, b, s, k = sp.symbols('a, b, s, k')
n = sp.var('n', integer = True, negative=False)
sum2 = sp.Sum((a+k*s)**2, (k, 0, (n-1)))
sum2 = sum2.doit()
sum2 = sum2.simplify()
sum2 = sum2.subs({s: (b-a)/(n-1)}).simplify()
```

Comment: `замену приходится делать два раза` - фактически замена у вас выполняется один раз, так как при первом вызове метода `subs` отсутствует присваивание. А про вычисление сначала с независимыми переменными, а потом подстановку - это общепринятая практика в таких случаях? Как вы пришли к выводу, что именно такая доработка решит проблему?

Comment: @maestro да, про два раза это я ступил. Что касается замены, то ошибка с `NoneType` иногда случается при суммировании, и, по-моему, её до сих пор не пофиксили. В таких случаях я пробую как-то изменить формулу, и потом трансформировать. В этой сумме `s` и `n` связаны выражением, поэтому логично было попробовать сначала упростить без учёта связи, а затем дополнить выражением для `s`.